# Relay Node vs Block-Producer Node

Tags: stake-pool

This might be a novice question, but please bear with me :)

I'm working towards becoming an SPO and have a question regarding setting up the two types of nodes:

- I have a Raspberry Pi 4 and an AWS, which should I (ideally) configure to be the relay node and which, the BP?

Regards

Comment: Welcome to the site! Questions sometimes get closed though for "needing more focus" if there's more than one question in one post. I recommend you ask two separate questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would probably want to use the AWS node as relay. This way you don't have to distribute the IP address of the Raspberry Pi in the Cardano network. (I assume you want to run the Raspberry from your home).

You also need to figure out if you have a static IP where you setup the Raspberry or if you get a dynamic IP from your ISP. If you get a dynamic IP, you need to make sure you either update it in your relay node every time it changes or you need to setup some sort of dynDNS service.

Answer (score 6):

The minimum RAM requirements are 8gb. You may think that the Raspberry may fall short in the short term. If you use it as a Relay you can disable the Tracemenpool to save resources.

Comment: You might like to make this a comment once you have enough rep!

Answer (score 2):

Rasberry for Block producers and Cloud for Relays, as the Relays consumes more resources.