# Relay Node & Block-Producing Node, which one requires more Hard Disk capacity?

Tags: stake-pool

As a follow-up to this [questions](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/529/relay-node-vs-block-producer-node)

Say, I have a SSD of 2TB, which of the two nodes do I have to connect it to? BP or Relay Node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both nodes need to download the Cardano blockchain and therefore both nodes need some disk space. Currently the space needed is ~25GB.

Answer (score 6):

The following graph shows the growth of the DB folder during last 100 days
[image]

It grew from 7 to 10.5 GB
In addition it depends on your logging settings and retention policy how much additional space is needed.

Comment: Also, `cardano-node` might not clean up forks it has seen in the past, so it might different from a fresh sync.